# How do I de-serialize an attribute and a text node using XStream?

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I would like to de-serialize the following XML using *XStream*:

```xml
<root>
    <node att="value">text</node>
</root>
```

into a *Java* object with two fields of type `String`. How do I do this?

I've seen [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23570817) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726863), but what I need to do is actually the reverse operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As hinted in a couple of the serialization examples you found, `ToAttributedValueConverter` is about the most direct way to do this.  It allows you to handle the fields on a class as XML attributes, with one picked out as the XML body.

With these two classes to receive the data:

```
@XStreamAlias("root")
public class Root {
    private Node node;
}

@XStreamConverter(value = ToAttributedValueConverter.class, strings = {
        "text" })
public class Node {
    private String att;

    private String text;
}
```

This deserializes correctly:

```
    XStream xstream = new XStream();
    xstream.processAnnotations(Root.class);

    Root root = (Root) xstream.fromXML(xml);
```